# Absolute URI not allowed if server is not a proxy

Tags: nginx, cherrypy

Today I ran an ansible deploy script that has been run 100s of times to make a minor logging change on the stage copy of an old system I'm supporting. After running it I get the above error message when trying to login.

Nginx access logs give the error:

> 10.0.1.65 - foo [04/Aug/2017:01:07:57 +0000] "GET /girder/api/v1/user/authentication HTTP/1.1" 400 50 "http://bar-stage/"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" "-"

The system is running a weird web framework called `girder`, but based on the logs it looks like the request is never even getting to `girder`. I rolled back the change, and system is still broken. I retested the changed code on dev, works fine. I run the deploy script against dev, which basically just does a `git pull` and restarts the `girder`, and it broke dev. Production and a second (unchanged) dev server are still working fine. We spun up a fully new dev server from our base image, same error.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

nginx debug logs for single attempt:

```
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 000055E4D62A8F58, pos 000055E4D62A8F58, size: 157 file: 0, size: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:157
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http proxy filter init s:400 h:0 c:0 l:50
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 tcp_nodelay
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http upstream process non buffered downstream
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http output filter "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http copy filter: "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http postpone filter "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?" 000055E4D62A9008
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 000055E4D62A8F58, pos 000055E4D62A8F58, size: 157 file: 0, size: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 000055E4D629ABCA, size: 50 file: 0, size: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:1 s:207
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http write filter limit 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 writev: 207 of 207
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 finalize http upstream request: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 finalize http proxy request
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free rr peer 1 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 close http upstream connection: 11
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D62B2E10, unused: 48
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 event timer del: 11: 1501870111101
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 reusable connection: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http output filter "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http copy filter: "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http postpone filter "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?" 00007FFC3E69E320
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 0000000000000000, size: 0 file: 0, size: 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?"
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/girder/api/v1/user/authentication?" a:1, c:1
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 set http keepalive handler
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http close request
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 http log handler
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 posix_memalign: 000055E4D629BB90:4096 @16
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D629AB80
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D62B7EF0, unused: 8
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D62A8230, unused: 224
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D629BB90, unused: 3797
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 free: 000055E4D62B2A00
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 reusable connection: 1
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: *1 event timer add: 3: 65000:1501869576102
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: timer delta: 1
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: worker cycle
2017/08/04 17:58:31 [debug] 2146#2146: epoll timer: 65000
```

Comment: Check error.log. Use error_log in debug mode if neede

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved, sort of.

`Girder` depends on `CherryPy`. `CherryPy` depends on a package `Cheroot`. For some reasons `Cheroot` doesn't show up in our pip freeze so we hadn't pinned it, or noticed that it changed. The ansible script updated it to latest, from 5.7.0 to 5.8.0, which for some reasons doesn't work with our settings and `nginx`. It does work with `Apache` which we got working as a short term fix last night.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Please report this kind of issues to [our GitHub repo](https://github.com/cherrypy/cheroot). This change was sent to us by the maintainer of Waitress and implements RFC 7230 and RFC 7231. I've fixed some problems it was causing, but it seems to break some compatibility w/ cherrypy. Could you please share your working/non-working reverse proxy configs, so I could try covering that with a test suite?

Comment: Yep planning too when I get in to work Monday. Just ran out of time trying to figure out where the problem was coming from.

Comment: Please check your HTTP traffic, which incoming for CherryPy app. I'm going to guess, that there are HTTP queries which contain Absolute URI form in request line, which is only the case for an HTTP proxy, invalid otherwise.

Comment: I'm still waiting for details, it is important to me to sort out any incompatibilities.

Comment: As per this [Gitter comment](https://gitter.im/cherrypy/cherrypy?at=599428c0614889d47553541b), the issue with nginx config might be missing trailing slash in `proxy_pass` directive value.